# Why does Microsoft login page prompt twice in AspNetCore?

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect

My AspNetCore TargetFramework is net5.0. The package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect version is 5.0.9.
The configuration in appsettings.json is as below
[image]

I'm calling HttpContext.ChallengeAsync for SignIn

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebUI.Features.Account
{
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        public async Task SignIn()
        {
            await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(
                OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    RedirectUri = ApplicationSettings.AdalSettings.RedirectUri
                });
        }

        public IActionResult LogOut()
        {
            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("SignedOut", "Error");
            }

            return base.SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = ApplicationSettings.AdalSettings.RedirectUri
            }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
    }
}
```

I use the Microsoft Identity Platform v2.0 endpoint. Authority = $"{Instance}/{Tenant}/v2.0".

Here is the implementation of the authentication.

```
namespace ULTracker.WebUI
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        private void AddAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var tokenProvider = new TokenProvider(new TokenProviderOptions { 
                ClientId = ApplicationSettings.AdalSettings.ClientId,
                ClientSecret = ApplicationSettings.AdalSettings.AppKey,
                Authority = ApplicationSettings.AdalSettings.Authority,
                CallbackPath = ApplicationSettings.AdalSettings.CallbackPath,
            });

            services.AddSingleton(tokenProvider);

            var sessionCookieLifetime = Configuration.GetValue("SessionCookieLifetimeMinutes", 60);

            services
                .AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(sessionCookieLifetime);
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(sessionCookieLifetime);
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.Authority = ApplicationSettings.AdalSettings.Authority;
                    options.ClientId = ApplicationSettings.AdalSettings.ClientId;
                    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;

                    // Set the NameClaimType to be preferred_username.
                    // This change is needed because certain token claims from Azure AD v1.0 endpoint
                    // (on which the original .NET core template is based) are different in Azure AD v2.0 endpoint. 
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "preferred_username";

                    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        OnAuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                        OnTokenResponseReceived = OnTokenResponseReceived
                    };
                });

            services
                .AddOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .Configure<ITicketStore>((options, store) => options.SessionStore = store);

            services.AddSingleton(provider => 
                new RedisCacheService(ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ApplicationSettings.AuthenticationRedisCacheConfiguration)));

            services.AddSingleton<ITicketStore, RedisCacheTicketStore>();
        }

        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedContext context)
        {
            Serilog.Log.Logger.Error(context.Exception, "Authentication failed");

            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect("/Error/AuthenticationFailed");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
        {
            // As AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode is asynchronous we want to tell ASP.NET core that we are handing the code even if it's not done yet
            // so that it does not concurrently call the Token endpoint.
            context.HandleCodeRedemption();

            var tokenProvider = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<TokenProvider>();

            var authenticationResult = await tokenProvider.RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                context.HttpContext,
                context.ProtocolMessage.Code,
                ApplicationSettings.AdalSettings.ResourceScopes);

            // Remember the MSAL home account identifier so it can be stored in the claims later on.
            context.Properties.SetParameter(Shared.Security.ClaimTypes.AccountId, authenticationResult.Account.HomeAccountId.Identifier);

            // Signal to the OpenID Connect middleware that the authorization code is already redeemed and it should not be redeemed again.
            // Pass through the ID token so that it can be validated and used as the identity that has signed in.
            // Do not pass through the access token as we are taking control over the token acquisition and don't want ASP.NET Core to
            // cache and reuse the access token itself.
            context.HandleCodeRedemption(null, authenticationResult.IdToken);
        }

        private async Task OnTokenResponseReceived(TokenResponseReceivedContext context)
        {
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;

            // See if an account identifier was provided by a previous step.
            var accountId = context.Properties.GetParameter<string>(Shared.Security.ClaimTypes.AccountId);
            if (accountId != null)
            {
                // Add the account identifier claim so it can be used to look up the user's tokens later.
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Shared.Security.ClaimTypes.AccountId, accountId));
            }

            var tokenProvider = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<TokenProvider>();

            var webApiToken = await tokenProvider.GetTokenForUserAsync(
                context.HttpContext,
                context.Principal,
                ApplicationSettings.AdalSettings.ResourceScopes);

            var webApiClient = new HttpClient();
            webApiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApplicationSettings.WebApiUrlAddressSettings.ULTrackerApiBaseAddress);
            webApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", webApiToken.AccessToken);

            await AddRolesAndPermissionsToIdentity();

            await UpdateLastLoginTime();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation of TokenProvider

```
namespace WebUI.Infrastructure.Security
{
    public class TokenProvider
    {
        private readonly TokenProviderOptions options;

        public TokenProvider(TokenProviderOptions options)
        {
            this.options = options;
        }

        public async Task<AuthenticationResult> RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, string authorizationCode, IEnumerable<string> scopes)
        {
            var confidentialClientApplication = GetConfidentialClientApplication(httpContext);

            var token = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, authorizationCode).ExecuteAsync();

            return token;
        }

        public async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetTokenForUserAsync(HttpContext httpContext, ClaimsPrincipal user, IEnumerable<string> scopes)
        {
            if (user == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"The current user is not authenticated.");
            }

            var confidentialClientApplication = GetConfidentialClientApplication(httpContext);

            var userAccount = await confidentialClientApplication.GetAccountAsync(user.GetAccountId());

            var token = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, userAccount).ExecuteAsync();

            return token;
        }

        private IConfidentialClientApplication GetConfidentialClientApplication(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var redirectUri = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(
                httpContext.Request.Scheme, 
                httpContext.Request.Host, 
                httpContext.Request.PathBase, 
                options.CallbackPath);

            var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ApplicationSettings.AdalSettings.ClientId)
            .WithClientSecret(ApplicationSettings.AdalSettings.AppKey)
            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .WithAuthority(ApplicationSettings.AdalSettings.Authority)
            .Build();

            app.AddDistributedTokenCache(services => {
                services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
                {
                    options.Configuration = ApplicationSettings.AuthenticationRedisCacheConfiguration;
                });
            });
            
            return app;
        }
    }

    public class TokenProviderOptions
    {
        public string ClientId { get; set; }

        public string ClientSecret { get; set; }

        public string Authority { get; set; }

        public string CallbackPath { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I click SignIn, it shows Microsoft login page
[image]

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/8a05c2ab-ceb9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxb039a79/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxx-xxxx-4f54-bfcd-af7d72500936&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44328%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637973555838466319.M2NmZTRlYTEtN2VmNC00MTJjLTlhMjAtMjQ4ZWMwMDZmN2ZmMWQ2N2VhOGMtMzFmZi00MGNlLTgwZTUtOTk3NGEyMzRiNTlj&state=CfDJ8L99Fb3JvfFAiwRD5r107NL4movayclD7Qt52v1OFqTe58X9RhIvSYm1PiqGyJusBes3CJzkRNSFJm31ZXcbhlOqqshw7qRmxQ_agJWtyQHdKAPUnhF9NZiZ3scgZyz3XBQzrRLMBWunJ8d0o36__hjVndtd4ynsNLYsdughSzk55-CB-0MIiJNrNNkIYNJXZn4jAjc0nWsTMm8540eGryD45A8isZjeZEGec08wCTp1cVxdV_7AP5WeYlgdmq4rsAHK-qSjCUa0u7NttKP9RmjbP7qq3TguCnKHD_Mub6wCpcLpu82SbCkUozdUfP2aRg&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=6.7.1.0&sso_reload=true
```

After I pick an account, it redirects to the URL below

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/8a05c2ab-ceb9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxb039a79/reprocess?ctx=rQQIARAAjZK7i9t2AICt88V3OWhyaUsIZDlIhtAi-6f3T4YMsnR-yJIsy_L5rA5GT0uyHtbD57PGdOmYOVtvKhlvKunSpR0OCqHQof0DSikEQoeSMdf_oMs3fcM3fEcHdJNpYk3wRR1vgvZTC4MWS9seSpssg5IeRaKWZzuo6TEOg1MAsASdf3p0_Osv719c32-O3jx-9yR58Oz318gTvyzXRbvVilLbjPy0KNskSeCwVQTLJEjQNHDs7xHkLYL8hSCv9wqaYFiGoCgKEpCkaQJjmzKuxIauRXP9tFTws1jhAZB1MZT0yJdDrpTDMWnM5K0sGLGCG7E8G-O3nj_qyaVcdWMjuPV7SiTpy62hT8uRviKU3ulOrrRA0aPwj737I25T-vh_SPOgcv_Zu-ulebxY3-a-qv-8x3uCCCWW7VqEeOF1uWCrCVSOAUaRyDi9MHd2JDDjksIvsFE3010KnrOaP7iYzGNMDbLeTtwUHbcgeLFaacqkK8YEZpzblh-Nsqzwt0ymxZfjhbkUZ-Vu3HeGnDpN_C6rGIFBFPbS2FXEeWdc5Zokd2abRIQOSAl6sfDDs8QpHXKXFIo0L5zN0p9UK4pC-Q4K5EEgKrmirAZzRTw3EjLkQhsks0KXY0iRwO3lO4GkOBgURugapz3XBnDL62vMPrt0zhYMp1Izdx4tnTgj84LrD9FsEvJTE2wYpSyHKqvFoaUyWUboyw2fDPvCQt5Y9JZf29J6A_GJxa-maeVMPRU3teV1_Sk0AWXjpoXarsWiJDQdlPU8FwWQcl0LEKzJsDf1e-naTQLnZJ2nXhC5b_eRv_cfHjaODx4hJ7Vnn4N6-_Dw6Lj2qHZS-7CPXN25He-nlvjDCPua_-6rCn7252Ht5k4LTjoqHI57OtNdzQSs0584oJzIkgoH-Cr3sf6XPR-o7k66hM9hG3vZQF42GjeNBwNhoZzqE51TBE4T8AV430C-Oai9uft_Vv7xk9qHe_9--9vVq-urd_2P0&sessionid=4d3e5c46-e446-4ae0-9403-271668df1367
```

And then it redirects to this URL and the Microsoft login page is prompt again.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/8a05c2ab-ceb9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxb039a79/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=b18b96cf-6a97-4f54-bfcd-af7d72500936&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44328%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637973560278134603.MTQxYjljOWEtMDcyYi00ZTI1LThkMDktYTQ3NjY0ZTM1NzQzYjU2ODM2ZTAtMmQyNi00MzI5LWE3MjUtNTYwZDViMzQyYTA3&state=CfDJ8L99Fb3JvfFAiwRD5r107NIK6JSldHEZ-dwJUuKbUVaxc-AJF6VBXETB9gTOxgycjgixhmnD9zcKKvdWELimEdGYT2w5DMcJ4RE1jSZkyIOTsRA7Gsk2xunFTzHCvmbg8BXKfSWtTcxByJo6GyOKrUmEWQclXj0fwk5sMId3QhFqGEddmvcBeF-R-BfRjDtjT4ghgGas1SsAHTq0FejisoYzoCkx85CUcQ5mFKLeBPf8J8xYN9tzZlKNRFKgtX8CeWnMVe4QSS3L1T1iUJziTsr4-N6scAYh0rHIkH5PMkLZoxcoWRpAQmicCTVX979RsKwFb9fqqZdHLrK9uYioVxQ&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=6.7.1.0
```

[image]

When I debug, I find that the method OnAuthorizationCodeReceived is triggered twice accordingly.
[image]

Does anyone know the reason? How to fix this issue? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated, but as far as I know, your logout method should not return anything, as SignOutAsync handles that internally, like in this sample:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults );

    //Important, this method should never return anything.
}
```